# Loop inside a transaction in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a method in C# that executes some queries to insert in the data base inside a transaction.

What I want to do is a loop to insert several "Phone Numbers"

```
// Creates the transaction
dbTransaction = dbConnection.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

// Creates the sql command
dbCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection.DbConnection;
dbCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;
```

... logic stuff

```
// Inserts the phone
foreach (PlacePhoneDTO placePhoneDTO in placePhoneList)
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = sqlStatementPhone.ToString();
    // Adds the parameters
    AddParameter<int>("@PlaceID", placeID, ref dbCommand);
    AddParameter<string>("@PhoneNumber", placePhoneDTO.phoneNumber, ref dbCommand);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

dbTransaction.Commit();
```

The second time that executes the loop fails

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the implementation of your method `AddParameter` and what error/exception you are getting ?

Comment: And what is the exception/failure? (I can probably guess, but you should include that detail in your question). Do you do a `dbCommand.Parameters.Clear()`?

Comment: What is the exception message you receive? Off the bat I would guess something like "the parameter @PlaceID has already been added"? You should maybe remove them after the execute non query, or just set them if they already exist?

Comment: Yes, the error message is: "the parameter @PlaceID has already been added"

Comment: Thanks slugster,
The "dbCommand.Parameters.Clear()" is working for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to clear the command parameters like slugster suggested in his comment. You could also move the command text outside the loop since it's the same all the time

```
dbCommand.CommandText = sqlStatementPhone.ToString();

foreach (PlacePhoneDTO placePhoneDTO in placePhoneList)
{
    dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();

    // Adds the parameters
    AddParameter<int>("@PlaceID", placeID, ref dbCommand);
    AddParameter<string>("@PhoneNumber", placePhoneDTO.phoneNumber, ref dbCommand);

    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or recreate the command inside the loop like so:

```
foreach (PlacePhoneDTO placePhoneDTO in placePhoneList)
{
    dbCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
    dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection.DbConnection;
    dbCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;  
    dbCommand.CommandText = sqlStatementPhone.ToString();

    // Adds the parameters
    AddParameter<int>("@PlaceID", placeID, ref dbCommand);
    AddParameter<string>("@PhoneNumber", placePhoneDTO.phoneNumber, ref dbCommand);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Clearing the parameters worked :)
I can't recreate the command because I'm using a transaction

Comment: It has one more solution but that is too bad :)